# iOS : Keyboard input accessory view wrong orientation when we start the application in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

In my iOS application most of the screens are in portrait mode and we have only one screen to show in landscape mode. So when I am starting the application in the landscape mode then the frame of accessory view is set according to the landscape mode while the other components are set according to the portrait mode so due to which the accessory view get separated from the keyboard across the application.
This issue arised after iOS 11 and moreover In iPhone X the issue is not replicable.

[image: When the app is started in portrait mode.]

[image: When the app is started in Landscape mode]

```
- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items {
    self = [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 44.f)];
    if (self) {
        // Set style
        if ([ThemeManager currentThemeID] == LightThemeID) {
            self.borderMask = BorderTop|BorderBottom;
            self.borderWidth = 1.f;
            self.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217.f/255.f green:220.f/255.f blue:226.f/255.f alpha:1.f];
        }
        else {
            UIToolbar *fakeToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
            [fakeToolbar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
            [fakeToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
            [self addSubview:fakeToolbar];
        }

        // Create scroll view
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [_scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [_scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        [self addSubview:_scrollView];

        // Add snippet buttons to scroll view
        CGFloat nextButtonX = 7.f;
        for (NSString *item in items) {
            UIButton *itemButton = [self snippetButtonWithTitle:item];
            CGRect frame = itemButton.frame;
            frame.origin.x = nextButtonX;
            itemButton.frame = frame;

            nextButtonX += frame.size.width + 7.f;

            [_scrollView addSubview:itemButton];
        }

        // Set scroll view content size
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(nextButtonX, 44.f)];
    }
    return self;
}


- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible {
    return YES;
}


- (UIButton *)snippetButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    UIButton *button = [InputAccessorySnippetBarButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIFont *buttonFont;
    CALayer *buttonLayer = button.layer;

    // Set button font
    [button.titleLabel setFont:buttonFont];

    // Set the button's frame width to fit the content
    CGFloat titleWidth = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:buttonFont}].width;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.f,
                              (44.f - 30.f) / 2,
                              titleWidth + 20.f,
                              30.f);

    // Set button action
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonTapped:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return button;
}


- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];

    UIButton *button = sender;
    id<InputAccessorySnippetBarDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

    [strongDelegate snippetBar:self
           tappedItemWithTitle:[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
}
```

Comment: Can you share some part of your code. Like how you are calling for Keyboard.

Comment: @ManishKumar I just added the code of how I am attaching the accessory view to the keyboard.